# What is the adjective that describes a person who takes everything in stride?

Tags: single-word-requests

I seem to remember there existed a word that is a synonym of *unflappable* but I can't remember the word anymore. I think it starts with a `c` but I am not sure.

Comment: Calm, cool, collected, coolheaded? Lookup synonyms for unflappable.

Comment: @Damila, I tried a synonym search and didn't find it. The word I seek is a little more specific, I think.

Comment: Equable (and the quality 'equability') are listed here with synonyms from Merriam Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/equable

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unflappable

Comment: Try [this link to the word _imperturbable_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imperturbable) at merrriam-webster.com, and scroll down to the section of the page labeled "Choose the right synonym for _imperturbable_" to see Merriam-Webster's views about how the synonyms _cool_, _composed_, _collected_, _unruffled_, _imperturbable_, and _nonchalant_ differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of "equanimity" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equanimity

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry you lost 'copacetic;' I'd never met it before. Lovely history.

Comment: Sorry, on further reflection I thought it wasn't quite the right word... but yes, it is a lovely word https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copacetic